# React-Bootstrap, Components notation as dot notation or CamelCase where is the difference?

Tags: reactjs, forms, jsx, create-react-app, react-bootstrap

I'm using react-bootstrap v5 package for create-react-app. When I import bootstrap components, there are components like FormControl, FormGroup, FormCheck, etc.
but I can directly only import the Form and use it like this in jsx:
`Form.Group`, `Form.Control`, etc. with dot notation, where is the difference or is it just the same as `<FormGroup>`, `<FormControl>` etc.?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the main advantage is that you don't have to import Form.Label if you already imported Form, you would have to input FormLabel and probably a bunch of other controls used by forms. Since forms are so common and need to be written fast, the dot notation is useful (I guess). Unfortunately the recommendations seem to conflict these days: they say write functional components, but also use dot notation... but dot notation is always better with classes, functions (especially anonymous ones used today) are like black boxes, classes are designed to expose internals hierarchically. The good news is react-bootstrap is written in a way that seems to enforce hierarchy like traditional classes; I can't really read their code at face value, but they seem to do it with a forward ref which is weird... anyway they seem to know what they are doing: https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/master/src/Button.tsx